# C Programming, what am I doing wrong? Strtok

Tags: c

In the notepad that is saved in the same file as my main.c program is,

```
ape apple
ball    bill    bull
foot
parrot  peeble
season
zebras  zoo
```

For example, assume that the word “bull” is in the dictionary. The word “bull” contains 1 ‘b’ character, 2 ‘l’ characters, and 1 ‘u’ character. Now say the input letters were “alblldi”. In “alblldi”, we have enough ‘b’ characters for “bull”, since “alblldi” contains at least 1 ‘b’ character. Similarily, “alblldi”, has enough ‘l’ characters for “bull”, since “alblldi” contains at least 2 ‘l’ characters. However, “alblldi” does not have at least 1 ‘u’ character, and as such we know that we cannot make “bull” from “alblldi”.

How do I achieve this?

So I just started to type this code and I need help, so far I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main( void )
{
    int found = 0;
    char string[SIZE];
    char name[ SIZE ];
    FILE *cfPtr;
    char word[ SIZE ];
    char *tokenPtr; // create char pointer


    printf("\nGive me a sentence: ");

    fgets( string, SIZE, stdin );
    printf("The string to be tokenized is: %s\n", string);

    printf("Give me a word: ");
    scanf("%s",word);

    tokenPtr = strtok( string, "" ); // begin tokenizing sentence

    puts("");

    // continue tokenizing sentence until tokenPtr becomes NULL
    while ( tokenPtr != NULL ) {

        if (!strcmp(word,tokenPtr)) {
            printf("%s : This is the word you are looking for!\n", tokenPtr);
            found = 1;
        }
        else {
            printf( "%s\n", tokenPtr );
        }

        tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, " " ); // get next token
    } // end while

    if (!found) {
        printf("The word \"%s\" was not found in the sentence\n",word);
    }


    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "dictionary.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        puts( "File could not be opened" );
    }
    else {
        fgets( name, SIZE, cfPtr );

        while ( !feof( cfPtr ) ) {
            printf( "Line from file is: %s\n", name );


            tokenPtr = strtok( name, "\t" ); // begin tokenizing sentence
            // continue tokenizing sentence until tokenPtr becomes NULL
            while ( tokenPtr != NULL ) {
                printf( "\t%s\n", tokenPtr );
                tokenPtr = strtok( NULL, "\t" ); // get next token
            } // end while

            fgets( name, SIZE, cfPtr );
        }

        fclose( cfPtr );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously homework so I'm not doing it for you, but: You can do it on paper well enough to ask a clear question, so just figure out how to implement that in code.

- A counter for each letter `int a=0; int b=0; int z=0;... (one variable per letter? there has to be a better way...)
- set your counters based on the input word
- check if the word you are searching can satisfy all of the counters
- There are a couple of easily identified common routines here.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int count(char *str, int c) {
    int n = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == c) {
            n++;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int check_word(int counts[256], char *str) {
    if (str == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (count(str, i) < counts[i]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }   

    return 1;
}

int check_words(char *word, char **words, size_t n) {
    int counts[256] = {0};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++) {
        counts[(int)word[i]]++;
    }

    int k = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (check_word(counts, words[i])) {
            printf(">>> %s\n", words[i]);
            k++;
        } else {
            printf("    %s\n", words[i]);
        }
    }

    return k;
}

int main(void) {
    char *words[] = {
        "bull", "bill", "ball", "bubblel", "babble", "bible",
    };

    check_words("bull", words, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I initially build an array containing the count for each character in the initial word, and then for each string in the array, I check whether it contains enough of each.

Running this code gives me the following output, which I expected.

```
>>> bull
    bill
    ball
>>> bubblel
    babble
    bible
```

meaning that `bull` matches `bull`, and `bubblel`.

Comment: This solution is more efficient than the naive count both and compare because it doesn't always recount for the word we're comparing against.